# Redux toolkit - Incorrect type in AsyncThunkAction

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

The error is simple

```
dispatch(fecthAllMedias({ destination, quantity: 5 }));
```

Returns

`Cannot assign an argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Media[], { destination: string; quantity: number; }, AsyncThunkConfig>' to a parameter of type 'AnyAction`

**Store file**

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import itineraryReducer from "./slices/itinerary";
import destinationReducer from "./slices/destination";
import apisResducer from "./slices/apis";
import mediasReducer from "./slices/media";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  itinerary: itineraryReducer,
  destination: destinationReducer,
  medias: mediasReducer,
  apis: apisResducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunkMiddleware],
});

export default store;
```

**Thunks file**

```
export const fecthAllMedias = createAsyncThunk(
  "medias/fetch",
  async ({
    destination,
    quantity,
  }: {
    destination: string;
    quantity: number;
  }) => {
    let medias: Media[] = await getImages(destination, quantity);
    return medias;
  }
```

**Slice file**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fecthAllMedias } from "../thunks";
import { Media } from "@/app/models/media";

const itinerarySlice = createSlice({
  name: "medias",
  initialState: [] as Media[] | null,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fecthAllMedias.fulfilled, (_, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export const {} = itinerarySlice.actions;
export default itinerarySlice.reducer;
```

So, anybody know how can i fix it? I also tried to export in store this

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

And add it in component

```
const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
```

But doesn´t work and return same error.

Comment: Please also share your `configureStore` call, especially the `middlewares` part.

Comment: Update with store file

Answer (score 0):

Please remove that `middleware` entry from your `configureStore` call. `configureStore` already enables the `thunk` middleware by default, and putting a normal array in there unfortunately confuses TypeScript.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});
```